# UITableViewCell - setValue: forUndefinedKey:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell and want to bind a custom object to it. The only option I know is to create a custom cell like:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:<SomeFrame>];
customCell.myProperty = someObject;
```

I'm curious to know if Objective C provides any other way to do this instead of creating a customCell.

While reading, I hit this document [NSObject valueForUndefinedKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForUndefinedKey%3a)

I tried the following and the app crashed.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:<SomeFrame>];
[cell setValue:someObject forUndefinedKey:@"SomeObject"];
```

**Crash Log Shows:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x5a846c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key SomeObject.'
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [associated objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to avoid subclassing. As for the `setValue:forKey:` and `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`, take a look in the header file (NSKeyValueCoding.h) for details.

Answer (score 4):

This problem happen when in the interface builder for the CustomCell nib, the File's Owner custom class is set to your CustomCell class.

File's owner custom class should be set always UITableViewCell.
Table view object custom class should be set to your CustomCell class.
Example (NotificationCell is my custom cell class):
[image]

Comment: Wrong. File's owner custom class should be set always `NSObject`

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the docs, `The default implementation raises an NSUndefinedKeyException.`. You'll have to override the method in your custom class if you want to use it.

Also, don't `bind` anything to cells, that means no retaining of outside objects inside cell objects. First, that's breaking up the MVC pattern. Second, you're most likely to run into problems with cell reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the MVC suggestion. Overriding methods didn't solve the problem though. I still get NSUndefinedKeyException.